# Teams Calling Bot - OnMessageActivityAsync return null value and AdaptiveCard not working

Tags: bots, botframework, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams, adaptive-cards

Trying to create and debug **Teams calling and meeting bot** from Bot Framework v4 for CPI project. found here: [CallingBotSample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/sbs-calling-and-meeting?WT.mc_id=email)
I have gone through all the steps correctly But I have some problems which got me stuck.

Tunneling with Ngrok work fine (200 OK) for `/api/callback` and `/api/messages`

Problem 1: AdaptiveCard v1.3 is not showing when the Bot is starting.

Fact:   I want the card to show every time the bot is starting as shown in this link: [Calling Bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/sbs-calling-and-meeting?WT.mc_id=email&tutorial-step=5)
[image]

Problem 2: `OnMessageActivityAsync()`get the request from user such as `createcall` However the `turnContext.Activity.Text` has the value But `turnContext.Activity.Value` returns `null` and that will result on **Bot showing message but not calling or joining meeting**.

Snip:

```
protected override async Task OnMessageActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(turnContext.Activity.Text))
            {
                //turnContext.Activity.Text = null;
                dynamic value = turnContext.Activity.Value;
                if (value != null)
                {
                    string type = value["type"];
                    type = string.IsNullOrEmpty(type) ? "." : type.ToLower();
                    await SendReponse(turnContext, type, cancellationToken);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                await SendReponse(turnContext, turnContext.Activity.Text.Trim().ToLower(), cancellationToken);
                //await OnTurnAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);
            }
        }
```

What I want is a 100% working calling bot that can **join any user calls and record it**

> Does anyone have a subjection or a solution to my questions?

Comment: Could you please refer this(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/calls-and-meetings/calls-meetings-bots-overview#:~:text=When%20a%20bot%20is%20participating%20in%20a%20call,it%20is%20shown%20as%20audio%20and%20video%20streams.) and check if you are configuring everything right?

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT Thank you for reaching out, yes the configuration is done right also with the Calling and Meeting Bot Sample V4 (https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/bot-calling-meeting/csharp)

Comment: Is the call peer-to-peer call or multiparty call? If multiparty, then multiparty call is not enabled yet in the Teams user interface

Comment: good question, it's a peer-to-peer call. But as the purpose is for calling and meeting Bot, my purpose is to create ta bot and add it to a team or channel with the purpose to listen to calls and recording calls. auto record calls and auto joining metting. that's my main focus.

Comment: Auto recording/joining doesn't seem to be feasible. We can create/transfer call using the bot and the userIds which we mentioned in appSettings.json will be able to join the call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We tried to repro this issue at our end, but everything works for us. We are able to get Welcome card and calls are getting placed without any issue.We can record the call as well. Also able to join scheduled meeting and Invite participants to meetings as mentioned.
[image]

Please make sure you have enabled calling and configured proper endpoint on Teams channel page.
[image]

Comment: Thank you for giving your time to assist me. In my case First, there is no ‘AdaptiveCard’ displaying when the Bot Start. Second, I would Bot to be able to join a call or meeting automatically. This is not the case with my Bot.  I don’t know what I am doing wrong!  When I debug it, it’s not showing signs of errors or exceptions… pls assist

Comment: I also did what you have instructed in the endpoint, but still, nothing changed. please provide me with the resource or guide that you used to accomplish this project. That way I may solve my problem quickly and accurately, otherwise, avail assistance, please.

Comment: We followed the same sample as you are referring: https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/bot-calling-meeting/csharp  FYI automatically joining meeting or any call is not feasible. Please make sure your bot is running in proper endpoint

Comment: thanks to you and your advices, I got my Bot working finally with an Adaptive Card show 100% as well. But the only thing that remains is that my objective is to build a Team-recording-Bot that can automatically join meetings and calls. Please confirm if it's available or if is not possible! This is very important.

Comment: Currently there doesn't seem to be any sample available for this

Comment: you save my day @Prasad-MSFT. This is clear and removed all my doubts. I got my Bot working 100% according to your answer. and I made sure to key the Bot account online to parse communications. Thank you